# How to attach dynamic JS function to a dynamically generated HTML control in .Net Razor Pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a .NET 6 Razor page application where I need to dynamically add several input fields (text box) in a Form, and I also need to attach a JavaScript Validation Function dynamically to the field.

The Metadata for the fields are kept in this object collection.

```
public class FormField
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FieldName { get; set; }        
    public string? ValidationFunction { get; set; }        
}
```

For example, here is one Field called **Age**

```
Id=1,
FieldName = "Age",
ValidationFunction = @"function Validate(FieldValue)
                       {
                          if (FieldValue < 0 && FieldValue > 100) return false;  
                       }";
```

Another example, here is one Field called **User Name**

```
Id=2,
FieldName = "User Name",
ValidationFunction = @"function Validate(FieldValue)
                       {
                          if (FieldValue.length < 3) return false;  
                       }";
```

The Validation javascript Fucntions all have same signature *(parameter name : "FieldValue")* and same Boolean return type. Only the validation algorithm/logic is different.

Now I want to render the form using multiple instances of this partial view.

```
<div class="mb-3">
     <label class="form-label">@Model.FieldName</label>
     <input type="text" id=@Model.Id class="form-control" OnBlur="SomeFunction()"/>
 </div>
```

I have appended multiple instances of this partial view in the **Parent Page** like this:

```
 <div class="formcontainer">
    @foreach(FormField field in fieldList)
    {   
        <partial name="_DynamicControl" model=field/>        
    }
    <br/>
    <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-info">Submit Form</button> 
</div>
```

The controls are loading successfully, however I want to attach the Validation function dynamically with the control's **onBlur** event.

How do I achieve this? Inside my Partial View, I can get the JS function string using `@Model.ValidationFunction` but don't know how to attach it dynamically with the control.

Comment: If your functions are all called `Validate()` then only the last will run.  Otherwise you could just add `<script>@Html.Raw(Model.ValidationFunction)</script>` after your '<input..' then add the function name as your `onblur=`.